# EXCEL VBA Copy certain columns from seperate workbook if they have matching string

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

So basically I'm currently working on a project that has over 300 entries, these 300 are pulled from a master workbook that has 1000+. They each have there own unique registration so what im looking for is vba that if the registration from the workbook with 300 entries can be found in the masterwork book to copy certain from the master into the smaller one. Had they all been in order I could of done this quite easily but due to them being in different orders I can't figure it out.

Here's what I have so far, what i'm trying to do is to use arrays, so that if an array value is found in the master it would copy, however it isn't working out for me :(..

```
Dim owb As Workbook
Dim test1(500) As String, test2(500) As String, test3(500) As String, test4  (500) As String 


With Application
.DisplayAlerts = False
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

 fpath = "\Work\new location\mastercars.xlsx" 'file location
 Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath) 'open file
For i = 1 To 500 'for each I 


    test1(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Carlist").Cells(i, 1).Value
    test2(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Carlist").Cells(i, 8).Value
    test3(i) = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 1).Value
    test4(i) = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(i, 2).Value 'declare locations

    If test3(i) = test1(i) Then
        test2(i) = test4(i)
    End If
Next
```

Thanks

Comment: You say it isn't working. In what way? Are you getting errors? Are you getting no results? Are you getting incorrect results?  Also, comment out `.ScreenUpdating` and `.DisplayAlerts` - you're hiding things that will help you figure out your problems. Uncomment them once your code is working correctly.

Comment: Hi @FreeMan basically the button lies on the master sheet and when I press it, it doesn't pull through the data to the smaller sheet, it only does it in order, if that makes sense? so basically, if the smaller one had all 1000+ listings in the same order it would copy, but because they aren't in the same order it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since they are unordered, you need two loops for testing.
You don't actually need an array, you can test the values directly from the cells, and you must set them to the cells (setting values into an array changes nothing on the sheet).

```
Dim Master as Worksheet
Dim Slave as Worksheet

'please verify if the master and slave are correct here
Set Master = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Carlist")

For i = 1 to 500 '(the slave sheet)
   For j = 1 to 5000 '(the master sheet)
       If Master.Cells(j,1).Value = Slave.Cells(i,1).Value then
           Slave.Cells(i,8).Value = Master.Cells(j,2).Value
       EndIf
   Next
Next
```

**Never forget** to turn **screen updating** back to **true**, or you will not be able to use Excel properly after that and you will not see your inserted data properly.

You don't need to disable alerts and events, they will make no difference. Screen updating can make your code slow, so it's useful to disable it.

Comment: Hi Daniel thanks for this I never even thought to use two loops, it should hopefully set me up, however when I have implemented this into my VBA it crashes my excel? Ive turned screen updating back to true also?

Comment: Crashes excel??? That's weird..... what do you mean?? If excel seems frozen, it's very probably the screen updating. Run a single sub only with `Applicatoin.ScreenUpdating = true` to fix that.

Comment: Yeah sorry @daniel was from my end that mistake, fixed now. I feel a pest but when I press the button that I have tried with a test master sheet I have A1: apple A2: banana B1: aa  B2: bb and in the slave A1: apple & B2: banana.. the aa and bb don't come through to the slave sheet. P.S I changed it from column H to B so it isn't that.. Thanks

Comment: Since you changed the code, any `i` or `j` mixed up´?

Comment: Sheet Names are ok? Try debugging (press `F8` to run line by line). Open the "local variables" window from the "show" menu and see the values, of things....

Comment: I will post what I have so far see if that helps? I swapped the master and slave around.. heres what I have (sorry its split wouldn't all fit)

Comment: Dim owb As Workbook
    
  Dim Master As Worksheet
Dim Slave As Worksheet





 fpath = "\\cor01nas02\gaskellc$\Work\Areas to build on and Residential Growth Sites\new location\test subject.xlsx"
    
    Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath)
   
Set Master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set Slave = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2")


'please verify if the master and slave are correct here


For i = 1 To 500 '(the slave sheet)
   For j = 1 To 500 '(the master sheet)

Comment: If Master.Cells(j, 1).Value = Slave.Cells(i, 1).Value Then
           Slave.Cells(i, 2).Value = Master.Cells(j, 2).Value
       End If
   Next
Next

Comment: Did you check in the debugger if the code ever enters the `if` block?

Comment: just checked it doesn't no, it only gets to "Set owb = Application.Workbooks.Open(fpath)"

Comment: Please, put the `DisplayAlerts` back to true, so you receive the messages about what error is occurring on that line. Probably the path is wrong. You need to pass the full path (C:\direc1\direc2\Work\new location\mastercars.xlsx). I suggest you put `EnableEvents` back to true as well. These may cause problems that you will never notice or know where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31271120/2344413) answer is excellent, but could be a bit slow because of all the looping (passing 5000 rows in the `Slave` sheet 500 times). It's also limited to only searching for 500 rows in the `Master` sheet.

This approach will review each row in `Master`, looking for the matching data in `Slave`.

```
Option Explicit  'require variables to be defined before use - always a good idea

Sub MySearch()
  On Error Goto CleanExit
  'Leave this line commented until everything is working as expected:
  'Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  'please verify if the master and slave are correct here
  Dim Master as Worksheet
  Set Master = owb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
  Dim Slave as Worksheet
  Set Slave = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Carlist")

  Dim LastRow as Integer
  'It appears you're looking for the value in Col H, change if necessary
  LastRow = Master.Range("H" & Master.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim FoundRng as Range
  Dim Looper as Integer
  For Looper = 1 to LastRow
    'again assuming you're looking for Master column H (8)
    Set FoundRng = Slave.Find(What:=Master.Cells(Looper,8), After:=Slave.Cells(1,1), _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
    'note: you can change LookAt to xlPart if you want a partial match
    If not FoundRng is Nothing Then 'the awkward but necessary way of saying we found something
      'I believe you want to set Master column 8 moved to Slave column 2. Adjust if necessary
      'the value we're after is in on row 1 of the FoundRng
      Master.Cells(Looper,8).Value = FoundRng.Cells(1,2).Value
    End If
  Next

:CleanExit
  'always make sure we turn screen updating back on
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This approach:

- Doesn't care what order the data is in in either the `Master` or `Slave` workbooks
- Doesn't care how many rows of data are in either - it will process everything in `Master` and look everywhere in `Slave`
- Will update `Master` Column 8 with `Slave` Column 1 when a match is found
- Using `.Find()` will be *much* quicker than looping through all 5000 rows in `Slave` for each row in `Master`
- **NOTE:** use `.Find()` with care - it will execute with whatever settings are left from the previous use (either in code or interactively through the menu) as the base, then apply whatever settings you give it in code. i.e. if you last searched backwards from the dialog box, this code will search backwards because I didn't override that in code. Nothing to be worried about, just something to keep in mind.

Comment: Thank you both for your excellent answers, I've finally got it working! :)